# Html float right

Tags: html, css

Hy, I am very new to html programming and I am trying to make a site. The problem is that I don't understand why I get a white space, in the right of my menu and image,even though I set the width to 100%.I am using Google Chrome.
Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Muzica</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Evenimente</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Intalnire cu fanii</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Concerte</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Lansari</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href = "#">Bio</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">Formatia</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Istoric</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <img src = "beregratis.jpg" height=100% width=100% />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css code:

```
nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
nav ul
{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-right:0px;
    background: #A0A0A0 ; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#404040;
    padding: 0 0px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul li
{
    float: right;
}
nav ul li:hover
{
    background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul li:hover a
{
    color: white;
}

nav ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul
{
    width:auto;
    background: #4b545f;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li
{
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a 
{
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #757575;
}   
div
{
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

And here's the link to the image: 
http://www.beregratis.ro/images/bere_gratis_2011_02.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should add `html,body{margin:0;}` as some browsers add margin to that element.

**Main issue** you are experiencing :

You are adding a negative margin-left on several elements (`.nav ul` and `.div`) so they can't go all the way right and therefore there is a whitespace on the right of image and nav bar.

Here is your code I corrected in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3ZTaP/6/)**

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Add

```
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

This will take away the browser defaults for the html and body element.



**2)** For the menu please remove the

`margin-left:-10px;` under `nav ul`.

The -10px margin left is pulling the menu to the left

Comment: And, if I may, this is the result with your modifications : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3ZTaP/11/ you are missing the negative margin on the `div` witch is the cause of the white space on the right of the image.

Comment: @MateiVlad nevermind. bsapaka, it would be good to edit your post though so you fully answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

try with a css reset, there is many of them, like this one http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

or just ad this at the begin of the stylesheet *{margin:0; padding:0;} that whill reset all the elements to margin and padding 0, if u have this kind of trouble the best u cand do is use the developer tool from your browser, go to metrics, and see whats that blank space, in google chrome for example, if that space apears in green its a paddin, if it is orange is a margin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CSS reset for all browsers behave the same way. I just tried to delete the negative `margin-left` in ul and the space disappeared. Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/qE69s/